# Can I create global IBOutlets and Functions?

Tags: ios, swift, file

Is it possible to create a link between ViewController.swift, and a seperate .swift file that I could call, lets say UserInterfaceHandler.swift?

I would like to be able to store all buttons, and views, in one swift file, so that I can easily navigate to different sections of my code whilst I am making changes and/or modifications etc.

I'd like to be able to do this for a range of different constants, including function calls.

I know in other languages you can, like in PHP you can:

```
include('global_variables.php');
```

and then call a function, or access variables set within the external file.

Also in C# you can do something along the lines of:

```
GetComponent<ExternalScript>().functionName[orVariable]
```

How could I go about doing something similar to this in swift?

Also, what is the correct terminology of such a thing? Because nothing I have searched for, is giving me any relevant results/information.

I guess an example of what I want to do is:

Create different swift files that can hold different resources (like.. UserInterface, GuestInterface, UserAnimations, GuestAnimations).

This way I could basically name every Menu view I create, as "Menu", and to access each different one, I could use something along the lines of:

```
UserInterface.Menu.alpha = 0
GuestInterface.Menu.alpha = 1
```

The way I am doing it now, is leaving me with at least 1,000 lines of different IBOutlets, variables and minor functions, which is - to put it frankly, driving me absolutely nuts.

All the best, keep on kicking.

Comment: You should not store all buttons and views in one swift file. View should be separate from Model and Controller. However, you can create a BaseViewController to contain all the shared methods and shared outlets, then have all your ViewControllers inherit from that BaseViewController, they will be able to access methods of their parent, override them and connect Outlets from their view to Base Outlets.

Comment: You can also create a singleton class to contain shared variables (persistent) which can be accessed throughout the project by including the Singleton swift file in the .pch file. Similarly The constants can be defined in a Constants header file, which when included in .pch, will be accessible from everywhere. You may also declare methods as Macros in the Constants file.

Comment: But mind you, I am speaking from Objective C background not swift. Swift can be different. But in any case, You now have the proper terminology and you can look them up on SO (I already found most of them here, but use google search not SO search). I was going to post a link only answer but then thought better of it.

Comment: The whole aim is to move away from keeping everything in one swift file. Thank you, I will do some research and see if I can find what I am after using the terms you provided. I will keep this unanswered until I can get to work what I am trying to do. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have discovered how to set and access different variables. Thank you. I have been unlucky in trying to create IBOutlets and Functions in different swift files though. If anyone else can pitch in, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@NSNoob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4029561/nsnoob), your comment did help me a little bit, but I couldn't really find what I was after with that information.

I instead had a little play around and I came up with the following, incase anyone else is wondering.

[image: fig a]

I created 2 UIViews, and assigned them each a class.

1. User:

   class User: UIView {
2. User Menu:

   class UserMenu: UIView {

[image: fig b]

Now, if I tap on Button A, the following code is triggered from ViewController.swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ButtonA: UIButton!
@IBAction func ButtonA(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Tapped Button 1")
    User().ShowMenu()
}
```

Which in turn triggers the following code in User.swift:

```
func ShowMenu() {
    UserMenu().ShowMe()
}
```

Which in turn triggers the following code in UserMenu.swift:

```
func ShowMe() {
    print("I am now being shown.")
}
```

The reason I was looking to do this, is that now I can store all of the IBOutlets and Variables relating to each view, within it's own swift file, and I can still work within the same View Controller Scene.

I can now use the ViewController.swift file as a base level logic handler to decide on what else to do.

If there are better ways of doing this, please let me know. For now though, I have answered my own question.